# CSS column-count in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

I want to use CSS `column-count` for the divs inside a block. However, since some browsers (eg. IE 9) do not support `column-count`, I want to set `float:left` for the divs inside the block.

But if I do that, `column-count` will behave in a strange way in Firefox. It works fine in Firefox if I do not use `float:left`, while it works fine in Chrome with and without `float`. Please see the attached image.

[image]

So, how can I use the `column-count` and `float:left` together.

Here's the `JSFiddle` Link: http://jsfiddle.net/V8KV6/1/

And here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="block">
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block{
    width: 300px;
   -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;     
}

.column{
    background: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;      
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an IE conditional statement:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<!--[if IE]>
 According to the conditional comment this is IE
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: +1, don't hack around for the browsers that work properly :-) conditional comment for IE is a good solution

Answer (score 2):

If IE support is required, you'll have to use JavaScript, for example:

http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

```
.block{
width: 300px;
height:220px;
-webkit-column-count:3;
-moz-column-count:3;
 column-count:3;
```

}

```
.column{
background: orange;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float: left;
```

}

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V8KV6/21/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/V8KV6/2/

check the jsfiddle.

```
.column{
    background: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display:inline-block;     
}
```

Remove the `float` and add `display:inline-block`

Comment: No, thats not the answer cos that way its not using the column-count property, its just using inline-block. See above image (chrome) to know how its supposed to work.